# What is the difference between tap , mouse left button down and mouse pressed events?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1

Well, I am developing a windows phone app in c# and xaml. 
 I found these 3 events similar to each other.
the tap event, mouse left button down event and mouse pressed events.
Can anyone tell what exactly is the difference does these 3 events make when the phone is just a touch screen phone. What is unique difference between these 3 events ???..

Thanks..

If you down vote this question then tell atleast what is wrong in my question by comments..Sorry if this is too silly question.

Comment: the one who downvote this atleast tell the OP the reason. Afterall he/she asked for it !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This QuickStart Touch Input for Windows Phone page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207076%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), and [this MouseLeftButtonUp Event page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.uielement.mouseleftbuttonup%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and [this Mouse Position page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb197572.aspx) explain the differences between the different events.

Basically, as per the links:

#### Tap

A finger touches the screen and releases.

#### MouseLeftButton

Is triggered in on finger release within the Tap event.

#### MousePressed

Mouse Pressed is the state of the tap while in Tap.

So the events are linked together of sorts. Someone with more experience with Windows Phone programming may be able to provide a better or more accurate explanation.

Answer (score 0):

For all practical purposes, the Tap and Click events are equivalent for a Button.

The Click event was originally defined in Silverlight for desktop Windows and it is only defined for the Button control (and derivatives such as HyperlinkButton). You can think of the Click event as the "traditional" way to handle a Button press.

The Tap event was added to the framework in Windows Phone 7.1 (Mango). Tap is defined in the UIElement class, which is the parent of many types of controls. You can handle a Tap event in a TextBlock, Image, and many other controls. Button is subclassed from UIElement as well, and thus can also receive Tap events. It is redundant that a Button can receive both Tap and Click events.

[reference](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/306daf77-ca95-41c7-b7e8-672789f8e6da/)

if u also read the second answer u can get some more info